# Python, how to import datasets with vertically stacked columns headers, @relation,@attribute,@data?

Tags: csv, pandas, dataset, arff

I'm trying to load a dataset from timeseriesclassification.com, but the datasets are formatted in a way that I've never seen before.

The .csv file looks as follows,

```
@relation Wine
@attribute att0 numeric
@attribute att1 numeric
@attribute target {1    2}
@data   
0,1,1
0,0,0
1,0,0
```

This is how the data should be formatted.

```
att0,att1,target
0,1,1
0,0,0
1,0,0
```

This is my current strategy:

1. read the file with file('filename.csv)
2. count the number of rows until @data appears
3. remove all the headers, and import the data with pandas
4. add new column names

Does anyone know what type of formatting this dataset is in? Also could anyone point me to a resource where I can reference different dataset formats.

Answer (score 5):

Use Scipy's [`scipy.io.arff.loadarff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.arff.loadarff.html) to read [ARFF](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) files.

```
In [94]: from scipy.io.arff import loadarff

In [95]: dataset = loadarff(open('filename.csv','r'))

In [96]: df = pd.DataFrame(dataset[0], columns=dataset[1].names())

In [97]: df
Out[97]:
   att0  att1 target
0   0.0   1.0      1
1   0.0   0.0      0
2   1.0   0.0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

That format is a .arff (Attribute-Relation File format) file. You can read it with the scipy.io.arff python module.